# How to combine nodes and break on new values using for XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

In the below example, I need a `FOR XML` query to say when the `actionswords` are the same, then combine the `content` under one node.

Currently I have this:

```
   <Actionword actionword="Bangs">
       <Content>Your heavy swing forces something to break off your opponent and snaps past you through the air...</Content>
   </Actionword>
   <Actionword actionword="Bangs">
       <Content>...a crushing overhand strike leaves your foe both broken and defeated.</Content>
   </Actionword>
   <Actionword actionword="Bangs">
       <Content>...a crushing overhand strike leaves your foe both broken and defeated.</Content>
   </Actionword>
```

(**note** how there is a `<Actionword>` node between each `<content>` node. Even though the action word is the same.

I need this :

```
<Actionword actionword="Bangs">
    <Content>Your heavy swing forces something to break off your opponent and snaps past you through the air...</Content>
    <Content>...a crushing overhand strike leaves your foe both broken and defeated.</Content>
    <Content>...a crushing overhand strike leaves your foe both broken and defeated.</Content>
</Actionword>
```

My source table is denormalized and stores a new row for each distinct `content`.

The table structure  is simply two fields, Actionword (nvarchar(max))  and [Content] (nvarchar(max)).

Comment: It would be **extremely helpful** if you would at least post the **table structure** (table and column names, column datatypes), some sample data, and what T-SQL you have already as a starting point!

Comment: The table structure is simply two fields, Actionword (nvarchar(max)) and [Content] (nvarchar(max)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a group by on `actionword` in the main query and get the `Content` nodes in a correlated sub-query in the column list correlated on `actionword`.

```sql
select T1.Actionword as [@actionword],
       (
       select T2.Content
       from dbo.YourTable as T2
       where T1.Actionword = T2.Actionword
       for xml path(''), type
       )
from dbo.YourTable as T1
group by T1.Actionword
for xml path('Actionword');
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the select statement?